# How to configure IPv6 routing from other computers to Teredo client in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, routing, ipv6, teredo

My computer (also router) uses Teredo to access and be visible on IPv6.

How to assign neighbor IPv6 addresses to other computers for them to be able to be routed to Teredo using the router?

[image]

What `ip -6 addr`, `ip -6 link`, `ip -6 route`, `ip6tables` and `sysctl sys.net...forwarding` commands should I use on hosts and on router? (assuming miredo is already working on "My router")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teredo is an 'IPv6 for one host' type protocol. You cannot provide IPv6 to other computers on your network with Teredo. Every node will have to do their own Teredo.

But Teredo is very unreliable. If you can use IPv6 provided by an ISP. If that is not possible then use a tunnelbroker like [sixxs.net](https://www.sixxs.net/signup/create/) or [tunnelbroker.net](https://www.tunnelbroker.net/). Avoid unreliable methods like 6to4 and Teredo.

Comment: Can I do NAT for IPv6 so all requests to Teredo will appear to be like if they oridinating from "My Router" instead?

Comment: Technically: yes, but you still have a very unreliable Teredo connection. All applications will try to use IPv6 and many of them will fail. You don't want that brokenness in your network... Set up a tunnel to SixXS.net or Tunnelbroker.net (both free) and you will be much happier.